Excel VBA Loop Copy/paste, autofilter, return value and loop
This doesn't seem to work.
I have one (1) Workbook, Sheet1, then other sheets named "1","2"...."15".
Sheet1 is where my main data is, while the other sheets contains data I want to filter.
I want to loop through all rows in Sheet1 and filter them individually in the other sheets. While looping, I want to make sure the value in cell "G" in Sheet1 matches the other worksheet names.
Then paste it, and call a function/sub to autofilter (I already have this figured out).
Then return the number of rows returned from the filter to cell "H" of Sheet1, that was filtered.
I need all this to be a loop.
Sub DataAnalysis()

    Sub ArrayBuilder() 'Loops through all rows and copy
        myarray = Range("A1:M1000")
        
        For i = 1 To UBound(myarray)
            For j = 1 To UBound(myarray, 2)
                Debug.Print (myarray(i, j))
            Next j
        Next i
            
        Dim wkSht As Worksheet
        For Each wkSht In Sheets
            X = Range("G1:G1000")
            
            For i = 1 To UBound(myarray)
                For j = 1 To UBound(myarray, 2)
                    Debug.Print (myarray(i, j))
                Next j
            Next i
            
            If Sheets("Sheet1").Range(X).Value = wkSht.Name Then  'if value of G in rows (that has been looped through)
                'matches the worksheet name, then paste
                Sheets("Sheet1").Rows("2:2").Paste
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End If
        Next
    
        Application.Run "'FileX.xls'!FilterX"    ' this activates a macro for autofilter and run it, 

        ' I can also paste the code here but that is not the problem right now
        X1 = Range("H1:H1000")
       
        For i = 1 To UBound(myarray)
            For j = 1 To UBound(myarray, 2)
                Debug.Print (myarray(i, j))
            Next j
        Next i
        
        Sheet1.Range(X1).Value = ws.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1) ' returns the row count on the filtered data to cell H for every loop
    End Sub

End Sub

EDIT***
The CODE THAT FILTERS - FILTERX MACRO
Sub FilterX()
    If ActiveSheet.FilterMode = True Then
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    End If
    
    Dim L(2) As String
    Dim M(2) As String
    Dim N(2) As String
    Dim O(2) As String
    Dim P(2) As String
    Dim Q(2) As String
    Dim R(2) As String
    Dim T(2) As String
    Dim U(2) As String
    Dim V(2) As String
    Dim W(2) As String
    Dim X(2) As String
    Dim Y(2) As String
    Dim Z(2) As String    
        
        L(0) = Cells(2, 12).Value
        L(1) = Cells(2, 12).Value + 1
        L(2) = Cells(2, 12).Value - 1
        
        M(0) = Cells(2, 13).Value
        M(1) = Cells(2, 13).Value + 1
        M(2) = Cells(2, 13).Value - 1
        
        N(0) = Cells(2, 14).Value
        N(1) = Cells(2, 14).Value + 1
        N(2) = Cells(2, 14).Value - 1
        
        O(0) = Cells(2, 15).Value
        
        P(0) = Cells(2, 16).Value
        P(1) = Cells(2, 16).Value + 1
        P(2) = Cells(2, 16).Value - 1
        
        Q(0) = Cells(2, 17).Value
        Q(1) = Cells(2, 17).Value + 1
        Q(2) = Cells(2, 17).Value - 1
        
        R(0) = Cells(2, 18).Value
        R(1) = Cells(2, 18).Value + 1
        R(2) = Cells(2, 18).Value - 1
        
        
        T(0) = Cells(2, 20).Value
        T(1) = Cells(2, 20).Value + 1
        T(2) = Cells(2, 20).Value - 1
        
        U(0) = Cells(2, 21).Value
        U(1) = Cells(2, 21).Value + 1
        U(2) = Cells(2, 21).Value - 1
        
        
        V(0) = Cells(2, 22).Value
        V(1) = Cells(2, 22).Value + 1
        V(2) = Cells(2, 22).Value - 1
        
        W(0) = Cells(2, 23).Value
        
        X(0) = Cells(2, 24).Value
        X(1) = Cells(2, 24).Value + 1
        X(2) = Cells(2, 24).Value - 1
        
        
                
        Y(0) = Cells(2, 25).Value
        Y(1) = Cells(2, 25).Value + 1
        Y(2) = Cells(2, 25).Value - 1
        
        Z(0) = Cells(2, 26).Value
        Z(1) = Cells(2, 26).Value + 1
        Z(2) = Cells(2, 26).Value - 1
        
        
    'ActiveSheet.Range("A1:AZ1048576").AutoFilter Field:=12, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=L()
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:AZ1048576").AutoFilter Field:=13, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=M()
    'ActiveSheet.Range("A1:AZ1048576").AutoFilter Field:=14, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=N()
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:AZ1048576").AutoFilter Field:=15, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=O()
    'ActiveSheet.Range("A1:AZ1048576").AutoFilter Field:=16, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=P()
    'ActiveSheet.Range("A1:AZ1048576").AutoFilter Field:=17, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=Q()
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:AZ1048576").AutoFilter Field:=18, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=R()
    'ActiveSheet.Range("A1:AZ1048576").AutoFilter Field:=20, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=T()
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:AZ1048576").AutoFilter Field:=21, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=U()
    'ActiveSheet.Range("A1:AZ1048576").AutoFilter Field:=22, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=V()
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:AZ1048576").AutoFilter Field:=23, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=W()
    'ActiveSheet.Range("A1:AZ1048576").AutoFilter Field:=24, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=X()
    'ActiveSheet.Range("A1:AZ1048576").AutoFilter Field:=25, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=Y()
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:AZ1048576").AutoFilter Field:=26, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=Z()
              
End Sub


You need to loop through the rows. This may be of use. Side note, in general (and in spite of macros being recorded this way) you want to avoid using activate and select in your code

Can you edit your post to include the code for Macro1. Where is MacroTest located ?, is it in Personal workbook ?

@cybernetic.nomad this is the best I could do, now i have just one Workbook to make it shorter,
sheet1 will be my main data sheet, while sheets 1-15 will be the sheets where I will be filtering data from. this is my code, but it doesn't seem to work.

It might be a good idea to qualify your ranges. Ex.: X = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G1:G1000"). You may also want to use Option Explicit at the start of your macro and Dim all your variables

Can you post tĥe code for FilterX macro, it will help me understand your code and test a solution.

Thanks so much @CDP1802 I will paste the code for FilterX Macro in a bit. And I will also try out your answer.

Is the FilterX macro in the same workbook as the data ?

Yes. Just one workbook which contains both the filter and the datanalysis code

It shows y instead of x in (x of y records found)

Best guess, it should help make progress.
Update 1 - added FilterX macro
Update 2 - revised FilterX
Update 3 - When there's an error code moves to next
Sub DataAnalysis()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range
    Dim r As Long, lastRowG As Long, s As String
    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    ' Built dictionary of sheet names
    For Each ws In Sheets
        dict.Add ws.Name, ws.Index
    Next
    
    ' scan sheet
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        lastRowG = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
        For r = 1 To lastRowG
            s = .Cells(r, "G")
            ' check valid
            If dict.exists(s) Then

                Set ws = Sheets(s)
                .Rows(r).Copy ws.Rows(2)
                
                ' apply filter and return record count
                .Cells(r, "H") = FilterX(ws)
                
            ElseIf Len(s) > 0 Then
                MsgBox "Invalid sheet name: " & s, vbInformation, "Row " & r
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
    End With
    
    MsgBox lastRowG & " rows scanned in col G", vbInformation

End Sub

Function FilterX(ws As Worksheet) As Long

    Dim rng As Range, dict, c
    Dim lastrow As Long, n As Long
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    ' configure filter column, tolerance
    With dict
    '   .Add "L"
        .Add "M", 0 ' +/- 0
    '   .Add "N",
        .Add "O", 1 ' +/- 1
    '   .Add "P",
    '   .Add "Q",
        .Add "R", 2
    '   .Add "S",
    '   .Add "T",
        .Add "U", 1
    '   .Add "V",
        .Add "W", 1
    '   .Add "X",
    '   .Add "Y",
        .Add "Z", 2
    End With

    With ws
        ' remove filter
        If .FilterMode = True Then .ShowAllData
       
        ' apply fliter
        lastrow = .UsedRange.Row + .UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1
        If lastrow < 3 Then
             FilterX = 0
             Exit Function
        End If
        
        Set rng = .Range("A1:AZ" & lastrow)
        'Debug.Print ws.Name, rng.Address
        
        ' apply filter to columns M, O, R, U, W, Z
        For Each c In dict.keys
            n = Cells(1, c).Column ' column number
            ' dict(c) is tolerance +/- on rows 2 value
            rng.AutoFilter Field:=n, Criteria1:=">=" & (.Cells(2, n) - dict(c)), _
                    Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & (.Cells(2, c) + dict(c))
        Next
        
        ' return count
        On Error Resume Next 'skips error code when no cells are found
        FilterX = .Range("A3:A" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count
    End With
    
End Function


Thanks for the help so far, it really made progress, but after filtering, it returns the number of total records. For example. If I have 955105 rows on a sheet, after filtering it just puts the number 955105 on cell H. Remember excels puts it as 1 of 955105 records found. It just picks the 955105, instead of the 1.

There's also a little problem, though I can manage that, when it filters  it filters the sheet1 also, and it hides the row 2 of other sheets where it filters, but that's not a huge problem. I just need it to show the "x" in (x of y records found)

@Pachino - see update

Okay I'm going to try it now. @CDP1802 thanks.

Thanks for your help once again, but I think the last one was better, because now I can't see when it's filtering it just updates the "H" value, though that's not a big problem, I can manage that..but the problem is, I cannot really tweak the filter unlike the first one where I can edit the filter any moment, for example if you saw my example, I skipped l, m, p, q and others with a comment ('). So sometimes I might not want to filter everything but this new code doesn't give me a room for edits, I'm really grateful for your assistance.or is there a way I can edit the filter to my satisfaction?

Sometimes the filter might be = value, sometimes +1,-1  and sometimes +2,-2  and sometimes all of it at once, simultaneously

@Pachino Do mean the 'tolerance' can be 0, +/-1, +/-2, etc and different for each column ?

I paused it to go check how it works. It removes my already put filter (which is wrong) paste the data on row 2 (which is correct) and puts the filter on row 3 which thereby removes row 3 from the filtering process, (which is wrong) and starts filtering.. then returns the value correctly.

Yes, it can be, most times it's that way.. about what I just explained I could show you a screenshot if you don't get it.

Again I greatly appreciate your assistance

If only the first answer could return the correct value, I'd greatly appreciate that...

. but the thing is, I don't know if the first one actually goes to the matched cell to filter,  because the filter all happens in the first sheet  sheet1 and when u go to the sheet  I just see the data pasted there and the row2 cell hidden,  so preferably, if this code can just leave my filterX the way it is, so I cam edit it anytime, but just call it in the data analysis function you created.

@Pachino - see update, You need to adjust the dict values to the correct ones. To add or remove column from filter comment out the .add lines. I would store the configuration for each column filter on a  sheet ( hidden if needed) so you can amend them without changing the code

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Well, thanks @CDP1802, I will stick to your previous answer before the edit, where I could adjust the array, this is too complex for me. Thanks for your time.
